# Endianness reading from file

Tags: c, file, wav

Hey I have a project that involves `.wav` files. 
   I found some ways to get the Header from this file but im confused by one thing.
   http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/
   On this site it says that some data is Littlendian and some data is Bigendian

   My question is: why does it work when im reading the data the same way and somehow its right?
   How come I don't have to specify in which order I need to get data.
   It's probably a silly question, but I didn't really need to get into those little details up until now.

```
 typedef struct wavHeader {
    byte chunckID[4];
    dword chunckSize;
    byte format[4];
    byte subchunk1ID[4];
    dword subchunk1Size;
    word audioFormat;
    word numChannels;
    dword sampleRate;
    dword byteRate;
    word blockAlign;
    word bitsPerSample;
    byte subchunk2ID[4];
    dword subchunk2Size;
 }
 wav_header;

 int check_file_name(char * filename);

 void list(char ** array) //argv
 {
    wav_header wavHeader;
    FILE * pFile;
    if (check_file_name(array[2]) == 0) {
        printf("wrong file name\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pFile = fopen(array[2], "r");
    if (pFile != NULL) {
        fread( & wavHeader, sizeof(wav_header), 1, pFile);
        fclose(pFile);
        printf("ChunkID: %c%c%c%c\n", wavHeader.chunckID[0], wavHeader.chunckID[1], wavHeader.chunckID[2], wavHeader.chunckID[3]);
        printf("ChunkSize: %d\n", wavHeader.chunckSize);
        printf("Format: %c%c%c%c\n", wavHeader.format[0], wavHeader.format[1], wavHeader.format[2], wavHeader.format[3]);
        printf("SubChunk1ID: %c%c%c%c\n", wavHeader.subchunk1ID[0], wavHeader.subchunk1ID[1], wavHeader.subchunk1ID[2], wavHeader.subchunk1ID[3]);
        printf("Subchunk1Size: %d\n", wavHeader.subchunk1Size);
        printf("AudioFormat: %d\n", wavHeader.audioFormat);
        printf("NumChannels: %d\n", wavHeader.numChannels);
        printf("SampleRate: %d\n", wavHeader.sampleRate);
        printf("ByteRate: %d\n", wavHeader.byteRate);
        printf("BlockAlign: %d\n", wavHeader.blockAlign);
        printf("BitsPerSample: %d\n", wavHeader.bitsPerSample);
        printf("Subchunk2ID: %c%c%c%c\n", wavHeader.subchunk2ID[0], wavHeader.subchunk2ID[1], wavHeader.subchunk2ID[2], wavHeader.subchunk2ID[3]);
        printf("Subchunk2Size: %d\n", wavHeader.subchunk2Size);
    } else {
        printf("This file doesn't exit\n");
        exit(1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: The endianness is consistent in any type. *The default byte ordering assumed for WAVE data files is little-endian. Files written using the big-endian byte ordering scheme have the identifier RIFX instead of RIFF.*

Comment: @WeatherVane Aside: Not that you implied this, but endian-ness of integer types need not match edian=ness of FP.  Not common but has happened.

Comment: So should I check whether its RIFX or RIFF file before reading whole header?

Comment: @chux good point.

Comment: @thomas1413 it can be possible to *deduce* endianness from some specific field, but you should know the style for any particular file type.

Comment: All of the items identified in the diagram [here](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) as big-endian are `ID`s.  A better way to think of the `ID`s is as a sequence of four characters (8-bit bytes) rather than a 32-bit integer as this avoids any notion of endiannness.  Beyond the `ID` fields, everything else in the diagram is little-endian.